# Finding any kind of "pattern" inside a random chart

Tags: math, graph

As a result of my mathematical research, I have obtained the next figure:

[image]

I am trying hard to guess the next value. I know there are multiple extrapolation techniques that can be used here.

*However* I am primarily concerned on trying to find any kind of logic behind this apparently chaotic chart. For the more curious, the X-axis represents the index of a member of a given population, whereas the Y-axis is just how far that member is from average.

Any algorithm/software to be used to recognise patterns? How would you approach this problem?

Comment: Is this a time series? Your description seems weird since negative variance makes no sense. One thing to try: take the Fourier transform and look at the spectrum.

Comment: I am afraid I used a wrong term. It is not strictly a variance. The Y-axis represents how far is a given element from the average value.

Comment: So the X axis is just the index of a member of the population, and the Y axis how far it is from the average? You should expand the description of the data in your question.

Comment: How is the spectrum going to help me? I can manage to carry out basic/intermediate maths, may you supply me with extra information?

Comment: Sure, I will expand it now

Comment: The spectrum probably won't help if it's not a timeseries. You have to explain the data better to let us help you.

Comment: Well, element " j+1 " in X-axis comes after " j " in time terms. That is, element 2750 will come immediately after 2749 and immediately before 2751. Time between elements can take as long as 1 week. Is this considered to be a timeseries then? If so, I will expand my problem description. Thanks.

Comment: This is still not clear to me. If X is an index, then why does it have a meaning of time? You should describe how you generated this data.

Comment: You might want to checkout Multiple Regresion to predict next values based on previous data.

Comment: Maybe I am not describing my problem as good as I wished. X-axis numbers represent events that come in sequence. I assigned numbers just to be able to distinguish between different events. Event nº1 is the first-ever event and comes approximately one week (something between 1 day and 7 days) before Event nº2. Event "k+1" has taken place 1 week approx after Event "k". These events are organised in the X-axis from start to end.

Comment: There are an unlimited number of ways of guessing at the next value. If this is a true time series (your initial description suggests it is not), then there are dozens or hundreds of books on the subject, and I'd be amazed if even one of them suggests that there is one best way to accomplish this task. Thus, I would proceed by developing some theories by other means, and then come back to the data to see which one works the best.

Answer (score 1):

The population sizes are sufficiently large for statistics to be useful.  Yet, the y values are all over the place.  It seems extremely unlikely that an underlying pattern could exist, when population is the X axis.  Common sense would suggest that nothing varies so wildly, yet predictably, with change in population.

If this were stock market activity throughout the day, you might have a similar chart, and underlying patterns might relate in some way to times various cities around the globe start their work day, for example.  Patterns would be plausible, at least.